# Offline R map with RggogleMap and Leaflet

Tags: r, maps, leaflet, offline, rgooglemaps

I'm trying to create an interactive offline map of Canada in R
After doing a bit of searching, RgoogleMaps and Leaflet seems like the best option. I followed the code here: [R Leaflet Offline Map Tiles Not Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42771185/r-leaflet-offline-map-tiles-not-loading)

Here is my code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/user/Documents")
library(servr)
library(RgoogleMaps)

# Load the tiles in working_folder/mapTiles/OSM/
for (zoom in 2:13)
  GetMapTiles("Canada", zoom = zoom,
             nTiles = round(c(20,20)/(17-zoom)))


# Start serving working folder on port 8000 in demon mode
deamon_id <- servr::httd(port = 8000, daemon = TRUE)

# Plot with leaflet
library(leaflet)
m = leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles( urlTemplate = 
     "http:/localhost:8000/mapTiles/OMS/{z}_{x}_{y}.png")
m = m %>% leaflet::setView(-76, 45 , zoom = 5)
m = m %>% leaflet::addMarkers(-76, 45 )
m

# Stop serving
servr::daemon_stop(deamon_id)
```

Hovever, when I zoom in/out on the map, grey tiles appear where they wern't before:

[This zoomed in image shows a grey tile over toronto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dPvv.png)

But,

[This more zoomed-out image shows toronto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAwbE.png)

Any ideas on whats going wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`nTiles = round(c(20,20)/(17-zoom))` 
This statement won't work consistently. If you want to get the map of Canada, instead of specifying `nTiles`, you can specify boundary like this: `lonR = c(-142,-52),latR = c(41,84)`

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as correct? It's my first answer:)